# Spring Data JPA does not work with String Batch

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-data-jpa

I have this database configuration:

```
<beans ...
    <context:component-scan base-package="my.company"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="my.company.repositories" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" scope="step">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="#{jobParameters['DBurl']}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="#{jobParameters['DBuser']}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="#{jobParameters['DBpassword']}"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="my.company.entities"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

</beans>
```

In package `my.company.repositories` I have defined a Jpa repo:

```
public interface UtilisateurRepository extends JpaRepository<Utilisateur, String> {
}
```

And then I use it like this:

```
public final class PaymentAuthorizedUsersReader {
    @Autowired
    private UtilisateurRepository utilisateurRepository;

    public Set<User> retrieveUsers() {
        final List<Utilisateur> all = utilisateurRepository.findAll();

       .....
    }
}
```

However, the context initialisation fails with this error:

```
[12:39:45][ClassPathXmlApplicationContext][WARN]Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.scopedTarget.emf': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
[12:39:45][CommandLineJobRunner][ERROR]Job Terminated in error: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.scopedTarget.emf': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.scopedTarget.emf': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:732)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:592)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.scopedTarget.emf': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:355)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:261)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.getMetamodels(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:26)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.getContext(StepScope.java:167)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340)
    ... 24 more
```

Is this a known compatibility issue between `spring-batch` and `spring-data-jpa`?

Comment: As far as I understood from my experience with SB the 'step' scope does not apply to object created by factorybean

Comment: @Luca Basso Ricci I agree, I removed step scope from `emf`, but as I already replied to @Michael Minella, now I get another error `Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.scopedTarget.dataSource': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread;`. I need the `dataSource` bean to get its properties from command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're entity manager (emf) can't be step scoped.  It's depended by on your transaction manager which is not so it will be needed too early.  Remove the step scope from your entity manager and it should work (nothing in the configuration for that bean needs it to be step scoped anyways).

Comment: I agree with you. However, after doing removing step scope from emf, I get another error `Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.scopedTarget.dataSource': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread;` . I need the `dataSource` to be step scoped because it uses command line parameters.

Comment: You can use command line parameters without using job parameters if you're using Spring Boot.  The alternative is to have that transaction manager be step scoped and use it only within that step.

Comment: I confirm that works just fine with Spring Boot. I think I will switch to Spring Boot. This is the future...

Comment: by the way, I noticed that when using Spring boot you do not need to mark your beans `@StepScoped` and provide `jobParameters`. You can used only `@Value` to get the command line parameters. However if you start your job programatically (as it is the case in integration tests) using `JobLauncherTestUtils` from `spring-batch-test` you still need the `@StepScoped` and `@Value("#{jobParameters['someParameter']}"`